# Refactor method to use class as parameter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, refactoring

I have this code where I add and remove items of a list :

```
    List<myClass> listofMyClass = new List<myClass>();

    public void DoStuff(List<myClass> listofMyClass)
    {
        listofMyclass.Add(new myClass());

// Some code here

        listofMyClass.Remove((myClass)someObject);

    }
```

I would like to refactor this so that instead of using `List<myClass>` I could use a List of anything as parameter.

Because I saw in the solution the same code with `List<myClass2>`, etc.

How should I proceed to refactor this ?

Thanks

Comment: Google 'generics'. It'll look something like `public void DoStuff<T>(List<T> listofMyClass)` when you're done. I won't post this as the answer as I don't have time to elaborate on the body of your method at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this?

```
public void DoStuff<TElement>(List<TElement> listofMyClass)
    where TElement : new()
{
    listofMyclass.Add(new TElement());

    // Some code here

    listofMyClass.Remove((TElement)someObject);

}
```

Code between `Add` and `Remove` **must handle generic type**. If you can't afford it, you can write many ifs:

```
TElement someObject = list.First();
if (typeof(TElement) == typeof(MyClass))
{
   var casted = (MyClass)someObject;
   //some Code
}

if (typeof(TElement) == typeof(MyClass2))
{
   var casted = (MyClass2)someObject;
   //some Code
}

// and so on.
```

You can also use my library ([link](http://genericinvoker.codeplex.com)):

```
TElement someObject = list.First();
someObject.DetermineType().When<MyClass>(casted => { /* action */ })
                          .When<MyClass2>(casted => { /* action */ })
                          .Resolve();
```

But remeber: it is "bad pratice" - you need to hardcode concrete types. Maybe it will be easier to write `Add` and `Remove` for concrete types instead of to make it generic with "brute force"?

Answer (score 1):

Use generics:

```
public void DoStuff<T>(List<T> listofMyClass) where T : new()
{
    listofMyclass.Add(new T());

    // Some code here

    listofMyClass.Remove((T)someObject);   
}
```